# Primefaces 5 Checkbox Multiselect Bug after Filtering

Tags: primefaces, datatable, multi-select

I am using Primefaces 5 with Primefaces Extension 2.0.0 And JSF 2.2 on a Wildfly 8.0.0.

I implemented a datatable using frozenColumns, filtering, pagination as well as multi-select provided by the built in checkboxes.

In most cases the Selected Items are submitted, but not in the following example:

1. No Items are Selected
2. Filter the Datatable Content with any Filter field
3. Select Items
4. Submit the Form
   -> No Selected Items are Submited

Pictures provided in [the primefaces Forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38735&p=122466#p122466)

My datatable's xhtml

```
<h:form id="jobListForm">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="no-border">
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="no-border">
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="showAllTenants" value="#{JobProtocolBean.showAllTenants}" rendered="#{TenantController.isSuperAdmin}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{FacesController.refresh}" event="change"/>
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <p:outputLabel for="showAllTenants" value="Show all tenants" rendered="#{TenantController.isSuperAdmin}"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <mx:tableControls managedBean="#{JobProtocolBean}" />
        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-s" action="#{JobProtocolBean.showExportDialog}" value="Export" ajax="false" rendered="#{Shiro.isPermitted('jobprotocol:list:xmlexport')}" />
        <p:dataTable id="JobProtocolTable" widgetVar="JobProtocolTableVar" value="#{JobProtocolBean.items}" binding="#{JobProtocolBean.items.dataTable}" lazy="true" 
                filteredValue="#{JobProtocolBean.filter}" var="item" paginator="true" rows="10"
                currentPageReportTemplate="(Displaying results {startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords})" 
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100,200,500,1000" filterEvent="enter"
                selection="#{JobProtocolBean.selectedJobProtocols}"
                scrollable="true" scrollWidth="50%" scrollHeight="100%" frozenColumns="2">
            <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{JobProtocolBean.items.preRenderComponent}" />
<p:column id="ACTIONS" headerText="Actions" width="120">
                <p:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="button-column">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-info" action="#{JobProtocolBean.startDetail}" ajax="false" title="Detail" disabled="#{not Shiro.isPermitted('jobprotocol:list:detail')}"/>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="#{JobProtocolBean.startEdit}" ajax="false" title="Edit" disabled="#{not (Shiro.isPermitted('jobprotocol:list:edit') and (item.stateSkipped or item.stateUnplanned))}" />
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-copy" action="#{JobProtocolBean.startCopy}" ajax="false" title="Copy" disabled="#{not (Shiro.isPermitted('jobprotocol:list:retry') and item.stateDone and item.cron eq 'onetime')}" rendered="#{item.stateDone}" />
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-e" action="#{JobProtocolBean.startRetry}" ajax="false" title="Retry" disabled="#{not (Shiro.isPermitted('jobprotocol:list:retry') and item.stateSkipped)}" rendered="#{not (item.stateDone or item.stateQueued or item.stateUnplanned or item.statePlanned)}" />
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pause" action="#{JobProtocolBean.startSuspend}" ajax="false" title="Suspend" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to suspend this job?');" disabled="#{not Shiro.isPermitted('jobprotocol:list:suspend')}" rendered="#{item.statePlanned}" />
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-play" action="#{JobProtocolBean.startResume}" ajax="false" title="Resume" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to resume this job?');" disabled="#{not Shiro.isPermitted('jobprotocol:list:resume')}" rendered="#{item.stateUnplanned}" />
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-circle-minus" action="#{JobProtocolBean.startUnqueue}" ajax="false" title="Unqueue" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to unqueue and re-schedule this job?');" disabled="#{not Shiro.isPermitted('jobprotocol:list:unqueue')}" rendered="#{item.stateQueued}" />
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-cancel" action="#{JobProtocolBean.startSkip}" ajax="false" title="Skip" disabled="#{not Shiro.isPermitted('jobprotocol:list:skip') or item.stateDoneOrSkipped}" />
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:column>

            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" width="18" />

            <p:column id="ID" headerText="ID" sortBy="#{item.id}" filterBy="#{item.id}" width="50">
                <h:outputText title="#{item.id}" value="#{item.id}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="TENANT" headerText="Tenant" rendered="#{JobProtocolBean.showAllTenants}" sortBy="#{item.tenantId}" filterBy="#{item.tenantId}" width="50">
                <h:outputText title="#{item.tenantId}" value="#{item.tenantId}" converter="JobTenantConverter"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="INITIATOR" headerText="Initiator" sortBy="#{item.initiator}" filterBy="#{item.initiator}" width="120">
                <h:outputText title="#{item.initiator}" value="#{item.initiator}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="CODE" headerText="Code" sortBy="#{item.code}" filterBy="#{item.code}" width="300">
                <h:outputText title="#{item.code}" value="#{item.code}" converter="JobCodeConverter" escape="false" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="CHANNEL_ID" headerText="Channel ID" sortBy="#{item.channelId}" filterBy="#{item.channelId}" width="150">
                <h:outputText title="#{item.channel}" value="#{item.channel}"  />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="SEQUENCE" headerText="Sequence" sortBy="#{item.orderId}" filterBy="#{item.orderId}" width="65" >
                <h:outputText title="#{item.orderId}" value="#{item.orderId}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="STATE" headerText="State" filterBy="#{item.state}" filterOptions="#{JobProtocolBean.states}" width="80">
                <h:outputText value="#{item}" converter="JobStateConverter" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="CRON" headerText="Cron" sortBy="#{item.cron}" filterBy="#{item.cron}" width="70" >
                <h:outputText title="#{item.cron}" value="#{item.cron}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="META" headerText="Meta" sortBy="#{item.meta}" filterBy="#{item.meta}" width="100">
                <h:outputText title="#{item.meta}" value="#{item.meta}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="MIN_FAILURES" headerText="&#8805; Retries" sortBy="#{item.failures}" filterBy="#{item.failures}" width="60">
                <h:outputText title="#{item.failures}" value="#{item.failures}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="BUSINESS_ERROR" headerText="Failure" sortBy="#{item.errorCode}" filterBy="#{item.errorCode}" width="80">
                <h:outputText title="#{item.errorCode}" value="#{item.errorCode}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="SKIP_REASON" headerText="Skip Reason" sortBy="#{item.skipReason}" filterBy="#{item.skipReason}" width="80">
                <h:outputText title="#{item.skipReason}" value="#{item.skipReason}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="TIME_STORED" sortBy="#{item.timeStored}" width="120">
                <mxtaglib:dateFilter dateProperty="#{item.timeStored}" datePropertyName="timeStored" headerText="Time Stored" tableBinding="#{JobProtocolBean.items}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="PLANNED_START" sortBy="#{item.nextPlannedStart}" width="120">
                <mxtaglib:dateFilter dateProperty="#{item.nextPlannedStart}" datePropertyName="nextPlannedStart" headerText="Planned Start" tableBinding="#{JobProtocolBean.items}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="TIME_QUEUED" sortBy="#{item.timeQueued}" width="120">
                <mxtaglib:dateFilter dateProperty="#{item.timeQueued}" datePropertyName="timeQueued" headerText="Time Queued" tableBinding="#{JobProtocolBean.items}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="TIME_STARTED" sortBy="#{item.timeStarted}" width="120">
                <mxtaglib:dateFilter dateProperty="#{item.timeStarted}" datePropertyName="timeStarted" headerText="Time Started" tableBinding="#{JobProtocolBean.items}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="TIME_DONE" sortBy="#{item.timeDone}" width="120">
                <mxtaglib:dateFilter dateProperty="#{item.timeDone}" datePropertyName="timeDone" headerText="Time Done" tableBinding="#{JobProtocolBean.items}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:outputPanel styleClass="ui-paginator-inline-span">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="ACTION_SELECTOR" value="#{JobProtocolBean.selectedAction}" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{JobProtocolBean.accessibleActions}" itemValue="#{JobProtocolBean.accessibleActions.value}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>  
            <p:commandButton id="ACTION_BUTTON" action="#{JobProtocolBean.startActionSelected}" ajax="false" value="OK" />
        </p:outputPanel>
              <mxtaglib:blockUI block="JobProtocolTable" trigger="JobProtocolTable" styleClass="block-ui" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Does it help if you add the rowKey attribute?

Comment: I tried again after adding the appropriate rowKey parameter -> still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the origin of the described bug:
The Javascript Object for datatables with frozenColumns provides a function to copy the 's reveived by an ajax request like in sort, filter etc.
This function doesn't take care of the 'rk' value which is saved in the data (jQuery data()) of the .

Original:

```
copyRow: function(original) {
    return $('<tr></tr>').data('ri', original.data('ri')).addClass(original.attr('class')).attr('role', 'row');
};
```

My Workaround:

```
PF(datatableUtils.datatableWidgetVar).copyRow = function(original) {
    return $('<tr></tr>').attr('data-ri', original.data('ri')).attr('data-rk', original.data('rk')).addClass(original.attr('class')).attr('role', 'row');
};
```

writing the data with attr() and the 'data-' prefix is necessary as it seems to lose the stored data as the tr is not yet attached. (I honestly didn't follow this one to the end so correct me if I'm wrong with this)